# Import-SPWeb error: "The file xxx.cmp does not exist."

Tags: powershell, export, import, spweb

I have a strange issue with Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb for SharePoint 2013.

I want to export one of my sites, so I type this command:

```
Export-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/site -Path "export.cmp" -CompressionSize 100
```

The exported file is 30Mb so I preferred to add the CompressionSize parameter ([see here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/export-spweb-import-spweb-could-not-find-file-exportsettings-xml)). Anyway, the execution finishes and I can see the file.

Now, I want to import it on another subsite on the same server:

```
Import-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/another_site/test -Path "export.cmp"
```

The procedure ends immediately with this error:

```
Import-SPWeb : The file export.cmp does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/another_site/test -Path "sisdoc.cmp"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletImportWeb:
   SPCmdletImportWeb) [Import-SPWeb], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletImportWeB
```

The "export.cmp" file actually exists (and has all the read/write permissions). What's missing?

Comment: You should give the complete path i.e c:\directory\export.cmp

Comment: Post it as an answer and I'll give you money :D

Comment: i updated it.happy to seeyour issue fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you command what i am reading you are not giving the complete path of the file location. So please do this way:

```
Import-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/another_site/test -Path "**C:\Directory\export.cmp**"
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way this is strange because the Export-SPWeb counterpart does not request an absolute path...

Answer (score 1):

According to the options present in the command line the import may not work. So, add or remove options untill it works:

```
Import-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/another_site/test -Path "export.cmp"
Import-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/another_site/test -Path "export.cmp" -Force
Import-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/another_site/test -Path "export.cmp" -Force -Verbose
Import-SPWeb https://test.mywebsite.com/another_site/test -Path "export.cmp" -Force -Verbose -NoFileCompression
```

Comment: This strangely worked.